# Tor, deleted term,exactness, $Tor_0$,exact sequences

Tags: exact-sequence, derived-functors, functors

Say we have a setting like [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~znorwood/partiii/files/commalgnotes2apage.pdf) on page 28. I have a few questions on the deletion of $M\otimes N$. One is that we loose by this isomorphism Tor$_0^R(M,N)\cong M\otimes_R N$. The second is why the deleted tensored sequence is exact *at* the last arrow $\to P_0\otimes N\to 0$? Finally, why did we at all erase the last term $M\otimes_R N$ in front of $0$?